# WCF Service error occurred while receiving HTTP response

Tags: wcf-data-services, wcf-binding

Error occurred while receiving HTTP response due to service endpoint binding not using HTTP protocol. This could also be due to HTTP request context being aborted by server. Unable to read data from the transport connection.Existing connection was forcibly closed by remote host

WEB Client Config

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
        <basicHttpBinding>
            <binding name="basicHttpBinding" closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00" allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered" useDefaultWebProxy="true">
                <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647"/>
                <security mode="None">
                    <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None" realm=""/>
                    <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default"/>
                </security>
            </binding>
        </basicHttpBinding>         
    </bindings>
    <endpoint address="http://WCFService:8086/WCFBase" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="basicHttpBinding" contract="WCFBase.IWCFBase" name="basicHttpBinding"/>
    <endpoint address="http://WCFService:8087/WCFExtra" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="basicHttpBinding" contract="WCFExtra.IWCFEXTRA" name="basicHttpBinding"/>
</system.serviceModel>
```

WCF Service Config

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <extensions>
      <behaviorExtensions>
        <add name="wsdlExtensions" type="WCFExtras.Wsdl.WsdlExtensionsConfig, WCFExtras, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
      </behaviorExtensions>
    </extensions>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="basicHttpBinding" transferMode="Streamed" />        
      </basicHttpBinding>     
    </bindings>
    <services>      
      <service behaviorConfiguration="WCFService.Web.Behavior" name="WCFService.Web.Service.WCFBase">
        <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" name="basicHttpBinding" contract="WCFService.Web.Service.IWCFBase" behaviorConfiguration="WsdlSampleEndpointBehavior" />
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://WCFService:8086/WCFBase" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="WCFService.Web.Behavior" name="WCFService.Web.Extra.WCFExtra">
        <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" name="basicHttpBinding" contract="WCFService.Web.Extra.IWCFExtra" behaviorConfiguration="WsdlSampleEndpointBehavior" />
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://WCFService:8087/WCFExtra" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="WsdlSampleEndpointBehavior">
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="WCFService.Web.Behavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
          <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647" />
          <serviceThrottling maxConcurrentCalls="3000"     
              maxConcurrentSessions="3000" maxConcurrentInstances="3000"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="True" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

Error in web client

> http://webclient/Common/Login.aspx|System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException: An error occurred while receiving the HTTP response to http://wcfservice:8086/WCFBase. This could be due to the service endpoint binding not using the HTTP protocol. This could also be due to an HTTP request context being aborted by the server (possibly due to the service shutting down). See server logs for more details. ---> System.Net.WebException: The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a receive. ---> System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host. ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
>          at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Receive(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, SocketFlags socketFlags)
>          at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
>          --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>          at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
>          at System.Net.PooledStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
>          at System.Net.Connection.SyncRead(HttpWebRequest request, Boolean userRetrievedStream, Boolean probeRead)
>          --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>          at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
>          at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan timeout)
>          --- End of inner exception stack trace ---

```
Server stack trace: 
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelUtilities.ProcessGetResponseWebException(WebException webException, HttpWebRequest request, HttpAbortReason abortReason)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.RequestChannel.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.RequestChannelBinder.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)

Exception rethrown at [0]: 
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
   at WCFBase.IWCFBase.PerformUserLogin(UserLoginVO aUserLoginVO)
   at WCFBase.WCFBaseClient.PerformUserLogin(UserLoginVO aUserLoginVO) in c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\WebClient\ec042b76\af1d169c\App_WebReferences.39m1idzl.0.cs:line 36589
   at Web.Client.Common_Login.pLogin(Boolean aIsFroceLogin) in d:\webclient\Common\Login.aspx.cs:line 178
```

Answer (score 0):

By default, the WCF project doesn’t support multiply service contracts. How do you host the WCF service with multiple service contracts?
There is something wrong with the client configuration. Is the client configuration automatically generated with `Adding Service Reference` tool?
Please ensure the service work properly before you call it.
[image]
Feel free to let me know if the problem still exists.